# Rails always include (join) on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a User model as illustrated below:

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :college
  belongs_to :class_level
end
```

I want to ALWAYS join with those other two tables returning one simplified User object. How do I accomplish this **in my User model**. I'm aware that I can do this in another model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users, :include => [:college, :class_level]
end
```

But I want to do this in my User model, so Foo.users will either be eager loaded OR be joined already. Is there a way to create an initialize this **in the User model**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use:

```
default_scope :include => ...
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an `:include` attribute too, for belongs_to.

Comment: okay, but how do I use it? belongs_to :college, :include => :user doesn't make sense... :include => true makes more sense, but that doesnt work

Comment: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3455-ar-belongs_to-include-option-doesnt-do-anything -> it's there, but it doesnt work

Comment: Are you sure you want it everywhere though? It is your app of course. Just seems a bit much for everywhere to need it.  I can see  2 or 3 controllers maybe.

Comment: Yes, I have 1-1 mappings that should always be included with the user, but are removed for data normalization

Comment: no interest in making this a named_scope (or whatever the fancy term in rails 3 is now... scope)

Comment: scopes only apply to the model, not the objects in the model. Could you post an example of what you mean though?